# Can I custom default queryselector of Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problems when using postcss-modules to obfuscate class names.

I add the prefix and suffix to start and end of class names likes `.ABC_className_XYZ`.

And now when writing JS(Jquery), I need to convert the class name to the same format.

I write a function to convert that.

But now, whenever i write JS(Jquery) i will have to write in the format `$(className("some_class_name"))`.

Does anyone have a solution to modify the queryselector, so that we only need to write the class of the element each time, without passing it through the name conversion function?

**NOTE: could somehow include all query functions like: `$(), addClass(), removeClass(), hasClass(), closets(), ....`
And it only changes with the class, the id and tag won't change**

Thank you very much.

Comment: This sounds like a overcomplicated solution to a problem of you own making. Why are you dynamically adding a prefix/suffix to the classnames in the first place?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it's a request from a client, I can't do anything else. 

Comment: https://www.tallan.com/blog/2012/01/18/overriding-jquery-functions/

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution, monkey patch:

```
$__ = (function(cls){
    const myHash = {};
    return function(cls){
       let converted = myHash[cls] || (myHash[cls] = className(cls));
       return $_(converted);
    }
}());
```

If you want replace `$__` with `$_` directly, or maybe Jquery has an inbuilt method to modify prototype methods, you might want to check that first

Comment: I was working on something similar when I realized that the selector could be somethign like `container#main table.data tr.main td[col-md-*]`

Comment: In that case he either modifies the prototype of jquery or creates a class/object that remembers previous selection.